# In Mapbox GL JS, can you pass coordinates to an external GeoJSON data source?

Tags: coordinates, mapbox-gl-js

Can you pass coordinate values as variables when trying to retreive an external GeoJSON data source? Ideally I'd like to pass something like this, but it doesn't work for me.

```
map.addSource('geojsonpoints', {
    type: "geojson",
    data: 'http://myexample.com/pins?lat={lat}&lon={long}'
  });
```

I am able to pass Z, X, Y coordinates if I use Map Vector Tiles (mvt) as a source.  i.e. This works:

```
  map.addSource('mapvectortiles', {
    'type': 'vector',
    'tiles': ['http://myexample.com/{z}/{x}/{y}'],
```

But I haven't figured out how to do it for a GeoJSON source.  Anyone have any ideas if it is possible in n Mapbox GL JS?

FYI, I am able to generate the URL using the method below, but the problem is it doesn't refresh when I move the map, unlike vector tiles.

```
var lng = map.getCenter().lng
var lat = map.getCenter().lat
var url = 'http://myexample.com/pins?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lng
map.addSource('EPC', {
  type: "geojson",
  data: url
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use GeoJSON to draw Tiles on the map

this is a sample GeoJSON:

```
    { "type": "FeatureCollection", 
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [ 
            [4.342254780676343, 50.89533552689166], 
            [4.342254780676343, 50.89443721160754], 
            [4.340830581474948, 50.89443721160754],
            [4.340830581474948, 50.89533552689166],
            [4.342254780676343, 50.89533552689166]
         ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    }    
  ]
}
```

after all you have to add the source and add the layer

add Source:

```
const sourceJson: GeoJSONSourceRaw = {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: data as FeatureCollection
    };
    map.addSource(sourceId, sourceJson)
```

data is your json file

add Layer:

```
 const layer: FillLayer =  {
        id: sourceId,
        source: sourceId,
        type: 'fill',
        paint: {
            'fill-color': color,
            'fill-opacity': opacity 
        }
    }
        
    this.map.addLayer(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question:

1. Update the data source when the map is moved
2. Use the map's extent as part of the GeoJSON source's URL.

You have part 2 under control, so:

#### Update the data source when the map is moved

1. Use `map.on('moveend', ...`
2. Use `map.getSource(...).setData(...)`